# Google maps api load/install fails in AngularJs app

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I am trying to use Google maps in Angularjs app as described here: http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use

I followed all the steps but I am getting following error:

[image]

My index.html has scripts in following order:

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src='lib/loadash/dist/lodash.js'></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<script src='lib/angular-simple-logger/dist/angular-simple-logger.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js'></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

In my app.js I have configured it as follows:

```
swarmsApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {

uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
    //    key: 'your api key',
    v: '3.20', //defaults to latest 3.X anyhow
    libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
});
```

And in my controller:

```
.controller('FarmersCtrl', ['$scope','$http', 'uiGmapGoogleMapApi', function($scope, $http, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {

$scope.map = { center: { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 }, zoom: 8 };
```

**What is going wrong?**

**UPDATE** : this error was solved by including `<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>` before `<script src='lib/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js'></script>` However it looks like not recommended way.

This led to another error:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing library. I think you need lodash for angular google map. See the code snippet in your given library link:

```
<script src='/path/to/lodash[.min].js'></script>
<script src='/path/to/angular[.min].js'></script>
<script src='/path/to/angular-simple-logger/angular-simple-logger[.min].js'></script>
<script src='/path/to/angular-google-maps[.min].js'></script>
```

Include the library and try again. Thanks.

Comment: Ohh did you added later. It was not there i guess. Usually underscore is not defined error caused by not including lodash in the application. Can you please check again whether that library loaded properly. Thanks.

Comment: from second error i looks like you need an api key. Get the map api key from google developer console and include it in the url and try again. Thanks.

Comment: I created a key and added it in index.js as  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>: MYKEY is actually a long string of value. Howeevr error still persists with one more error stating initmap is not a function

Comment: So now api key problem is solved. So now the error is showing because somehow your init map method is loading before the google map js loads. Can you load your init map code after google map loads its js. Let me know.

Comment: Problem was solved like in the following way. Looks like lodash.js wasn't loaded properly as you mentioned, however don't know why! Thanks though!

Comment: Ahh always feels good when a problem is solved. You are most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I referred this post: 
http://codepen.io/netsi1964/post/angularjs-google-maps-directive and replaced downloaded loadash in lib folder with

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```